# Functor instance of kind *

Tags: haskell

I have newtype:

```hs
newtype Foo = Foo ([Int])
```

I would like to simply apply `Int -> Int` function over it like it is possible with fmap.

I thought it will be enough to derive or implement `Functor` instance, but it requires type of `* -> *` kind.

**Is there some builtin way to make my type partially `fmap`-able?**

Comment: Short answer: this type cannot be a `Functor`, as functors must have at least one type variable. For instance, `newtype Foo' a = Foo' ([a])` would be a functor. However, even though this is not a functor, it is still entirely possible to write a mapping function `foomap :: (Int -> Int) -> Foo -> Foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before getting carried away, you should keep in mind that you're trying to avoid (1) naming and (2) writing the monomorphic function:

```
mapFoo :: (Int -> Int) -> (Foo -> Foo)
mapFoo f (Foo ints) = Foo (f <$> ints)
```

If you *really* don't want to give this function a separate name *and* want GHC to write the function for you, I think the only sensible way is to re-define your type as a proper functor of kind `* -> *` with an automatically derived instance:

```
newtype FooF a = Foo [a] deriving (Functor)
```

and then define a type alias for the specialization to `Int`:

```
type Foo = FooF Int
```

This is not precisely equivalent to your original definition of `Foo`.  In particular, the following expression in isolation:

```
Foo [1,2,3]
```

will have type `Num a => FooF a` instead of type `Foo = FooF Int`, so GHC may fail to infer types in all the places it used to.  But, this `Foo` type alias will *mostly* behave like your original `Foo` newtype and will allow you to write:

```
fmap (*5) $ Foo [1,2,3]
```

and such.

On the other hand, if you want to keep your newtype the same, don't mind writing the function yourself, yet don't want to give that function a separate name, you can't use `fmap` (at least not without overriding the prelude definition, which kind of defeats the purpose).  However, as per @leftroundabout's answer, you can use `omap` from the `mono-traversable` package.  Because this requires you to define the function yourself in a `MonoFunctor Foo` instance (e.g., using the same definition as `mapFoo` above), there's no real point unless you're doing this for a bunch of non-functors besides `Foo` and want to use a single `omap` name for all of them or want to write functions that can handle any such `MonoFunctor` uniformly.

Answer (score 8):

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies      #-}

type instance Element Foo = Int

instance MonoFunctor Foo where
  -- omap :: (Int -> Int) -> Foo -> Foo
  omap = ...
```